# Scrapy not extracting data from a certain xpath

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to extract some data from an amazon product page.

What I'm looking for is getting the images from the products. For example:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B072L7PVNQ?pf_rd_p=1581d9f4-062f-453c-b69e-0f3e00ba2652&pf_rd_r=48QP07X56PTH002QVCPM&th=1&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B072L7PVNQ)

By using the XPath

```
//script[contains(., "ImageBlockATF")]/text()
```

I get the part of the source code that contains the urls, but 2 options pop up in the chrome XPath helper.

By trying things out with XPaths I ended up using this:

```
//*[contains(@type, "text/javascript") and contains(.,"ImageBlockATF") and not(contains(.,"jQuery"))]
```

Which gives me exclusively the data I need.

The problem that I'm having is that, for certain products ( it can happen within 2 pairs of different shoes) sometimes I can extract the data and other times nothing comes out. I extract by doing:

```
imagenesString = response.xpath('//*[contains(@type, "text/javascript") and contains(.,"ImageBlockATF") and not(contains(.,"jQuery"))]').extract()
```

If I use the chrome xpath helper, the data always appears with the xpath above but in the program itself sometimes it appears, sometimes not. I know sometimes the script that the console reads is different than the one that appears on the site but I'm struggling with this one, because sometimes it works, sometimes it does not. Any ideas on what could be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found your problem: Its a captcha.

Follow these steps to reproduce:

#### 1. run [scrapy shell](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html)

```sh
scrapy shell https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B072L7PVNQ?pf_rd_p=1581d9f4-062f-453c-b69e-0f3e00ba2652&pf_rd_r=48QP07X56PTH002QVCPM&th=1&psc=1
```

#### 2. [view response](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html#available-shortcuts) like scrapy

```sh
view(respone)
```

When executing this I sometimes got a captcha.
Hope this points you in the right direction.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the help!. So what I'm seeing in response is basically the source code that my spider tries to read when I try to parse the items?

Comment: right. 'view(response)' should open your web browser which renders the response exactly like scapy sees it.

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot